# Is it anti-pattern to inject additional services to a decorator class?

Tags: angular, oop

To use in my whole application, I wanted to create my own Title class, because I wanted to add flavors on *setTitle()* function. In some components, I just want to setTitle of Title class of (@angular/platform), in some components, I want to pass a translation key (something like 'MY_USERS_PAGE_TITLE'), get the translation and then set the title.

I tried to extend Title class but failed. Because it's written that it is a **final** class [in the docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title).

Then I created an injectable decorator;

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
class TitleDecorator implements ITitle{
    protected title!: string;

    constructor(
        protected titleService: Title
    ) { }
    
    setTitle(newTitle: string): void {
        this.titleService.setTitle(newTitle);
    }

    getTitle(): string {
        return this.titleService.getTitle();
    }

    addTrailing(trailing: string): void {
        this.title += trailing;
        this.setTitle(this.title);
    }
}
```

and my translatable Title Decorator is something like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TitleServiceTranslatable extends TitleDecorator{
    constructor(
        private translateService: TranslateService,
        protected titleService: Title
    ) {
        super(titleService);
    }
    
    private subscriptions = new Subscription();

    setTitle(newTitle: string): void {
        this.subscriptions.add(
            this.translateService.get(newTitle).subscribe(title => {
                this.title = title;
                super.setTitle(this.title);
                this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
            })
        );
    }

}
```

Everything looks working and quite normal. But I had this question in my mind:

Since Angular DI automatically passes translate service directly from Modules, I didn't face any problems, but this way the decorators are not replaceable with each other (in theory, not in Angular), so it feels kind of wrong.

I would be happy with any suggestions & better solutions.

Comment: Why do you say they aren't replaceable with each other?

Comment: Did you check out [this page](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) of docs?

Comment: Imagine I create TitleDecorator myself, I have to do something like this new TitleServiceTranslatable(translateService, titleService) for one decorator and new TitleDecorator(translateService). So in this case you can not replace one with other.

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina yes, I knew about injector and tokens, but that just makes it working, does not answer my question :/ The solution i found is also working but I'm not sure if it's the correct solution

Comment: Yes, if you had to instantiate those classes. Luckily there's DI and IOC in Angular and you don't have to care about this aspect

Comment: So, you think it's a proper solution?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you can replace your services like: `{ provide: TitleDecorator, useClass: TitleServiceTranslatable }`. But maybe I didn't really understand what you mean by "replacing"

Comment: I was trying to say, you are right that I can replace it thanks to Angular's DI and IOC, but thinking in pure OOP, they are not totally replaceable.

Comment: Yes, but Angular isn't pure OOP, it's barely OOP :) I think your solution is totally fine

Comment: I guess you're right, there's no framework which's pure OOP :/

Answer (score 1):

> but this way the decorators are not replaceable with each other

They are replaciable:

```
interface IRequest
{
    id: string
}

class Foo implements IRequest
{
    id: string = 'Foo'
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    
}


class Test
{
    FooBar(request: IRequest) 
    {
        console.log(request.id)
    }
}

let test = new Test();
test.FooBar(new Foo()) // OUTPUT: Foo
test.FooBar(new Bar()) // OUTPUT: Foo
```

### UPDATE:

It looks like `ITitle` is interface. So we can implement this interface in any class and this class can
be injected as a dependency.

Your implementation is perfectly fine to me. Because you use inheritance. By doing this you reused behaviour of TitleDecorator class.

However, you can implement your interface in another class if you want to have different implementation.

So let me show an example:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
class TitleServiceTranslatableDecorator implements ITitle{
    protected title!: string;
    private subscriptions = new Subscription();
    
    constructor(
        protected titleService: Title,
        private translateService: TranslateService
    ) { }
    
    setTitle(newTitle: string): void {
        this.subscriptions.add(
            this.translateService.get(newTitle).subscribe(title => {
                this.title = title;
                super.setTitle(this.title);
                this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
            })
    );
}

    getTitle(): string {
        // your another code here
    }

    addTrailing(trailing: string): void {
        // your another code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's another solution. Thanks!